Strange error when calling RANDOM function in Teradata from .Net
I have the following piece of code:
try
{
    var con = new TdConnection("....");
    var com = new TdCommand("SELECT MyID, RANDOM(?, ?)  FROM MyTable", con);

    var p1 = new TdParameter("p1", TdType.Integer) { Value = 10 };
    var p2 = new TdParameter("p2", TdType.Integer) { Value = 20 };

    com.Parameters.AddRange([p1, p2]);

    var adp = new TdDataAdapter(com);
    var dt = new DataTable();

    adp.Fill(dt);
}
catch(TdException tde)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tde.Message);
}

It returns the following error message:

[Teradata Database] [3707] Syntax error, expected something like an integer or a decimal number or a floating point number or '+' or '-' between '(' and '?'.

There are other Teradata functions that I can happily call using parameters. Simply replacing the ? placeholder with numbers works fine too. Very strange.

Teradata's RANDOM function requires the arguments to be integer literals. They can't be expressions.
